# Loading json data into CycleJS app

Tags: javascript, cyclejs

I'm trying to wrap my head around CycleJS but I'm stuck! I'm trying to put a small app together that loads a JSON file containing an array of objects, but I can't get the app to execute the http request

Here in my code so far

```js
'use strict';

import Rx from 'rx';
import Cycle from '@cycle/core';
import {h, makeDOMDriver} from '@cycle/dom';
import {makeHTTPDriver} from '@cycle/http';

function intent(DOM) {
    return {
        edit: DOM.select('div')
            .events('click')
            .map(evt => evt.target.value),
        add: DOM.select('div')
            .events('click')
            .map(evt => evt.target.value)
    };
}

function model(actions, response) {
    return response
}

function view(state) {
    return state.map(item => {
        h('div', [
            item.map(todo => h('div', todo.title))
        ])
    });
}

function main(sources) {
    const URL = 'http://localhost:3000/js/planinator/data.json';

    let response = sources.HTTP
        .mergeAll()
        .map(res => res.body)
        .startWith([]);

    const actions = intent(sources.DOM);
    const state = model(actions, response);

    return {
        DOM: view(state),
        HTTP: Rx.Observable.of(URL)
    }
}

Cycle.run(main, {
    DOM: makeDOMDriver('#appmount'),
    HTTP: makeHTTPDriver()
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve is; load JSON data and render it as div tags for now.

When I run the code in chrome I get this in the console

```
bundle.js:14182 TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined(…)
```

I have checked the questions found by stackoverflow, but they didn't get me ay further

Comment: Did you mean to call view with `sources.HTTP`, or with `request`?

Comment: I am not sure from your code, you will need some where the state.map() to map to the div.  This example might get you on the right track https://github.com/cyclejs/examples/blob/master/http-search-github/src/main.js

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Cycle.js :)

The first issue that I notice, is that the HTTP driver will first expect an Observable of an http request, where at the moment you are simply passing it a string of a url. This can be done by wrapping the URL in an Observable using Rx's `Rx.Observable.of(URL)`

```
function main(sources) {
  ...
  return {
    ...
    HTTP: Rx.Observable.of(URL)
  }
 }
```

Next, I notice that your `request` (which is actually your response!), is misusing the HTTP driver a bit. The HTTP driver returns a higher-order Observable back to main, or in other words, it returns an Observable that contains other observables. This can easily be rectified with a `mergeAll()` or a `switch()`. `mergeAll()` and `switch()` effectively takes a higher-order observable, and 'flattens' it into an observable that contains the events of the 'inner' observables.

```
let response = sources.HTTP
  .mergeAll()
  .filter(....)
  .map(....)
  .startWith([])
```

The distinction between the two methods are subtle, but very important.
`mergeAll()` has a concurrency of `Infinity`. What does that even mean? `mergeAll()` will take all of the inner observables and subscribe to them, and push their events to the containing observable, while never unsubscribing. `switch()` is similar but with the concurrency of 1. It will only subscribe to the latest inner observable, whilst disposing of the previous.

I can't be for sure this answers all of your question, but I hope it at least gets your started in the right direction! :)